# load .wav from MATLAB gui to workspace

Tags: q, matlab-guide

I am trying to take input from MATLAB GUI.. which is `.wav` file, I
 have used

```
uigetfile({'*.wav'},'File Selector');
```

to select the file. But selected `.wav` a file hasn't appeared in the workspace, I need `.wav` file for further analysis.

Answer (score 0):

When using `uigetfile` you have to specufy the output variables in which to store the `name` and the `path` of the selected file:

```
[f_name,f_path,sts]=uigetfile({'*.wav'},'File Selector')
```

You should also check is the user selected "Cancel" (if he aborted the selection); to do this you can use the third output (`sts` in the above example): it will be set to `0` in case of "Cancel".

You can then load the `"wav` file using the fucntion `aurdioread`.

If you are working with a GUI and then selecting and areading the `wav` file in a `callback`, you can use the function `guidata` to store the data in the GUI data srtuct in order to be able, later on, to retrieve the data and / or to share them across different `callback`.

In the following a possible implementation (the `fullfile` function is used to generate the full name of the file - "path\file_name):

```
% Get the file
[f_name,f_path,sts]=uigetfile({'*.wav'},'File Selector')
% If the user selected a file (if he did not click "Cancel")
if(sts)
   % Load the ".wav" file
   [sampled_data,sample_rate]=audioread(fullfile(f_path,f_name));
end

% Get the GUI data
my_guidata=guidata(gcf)
% Add the ".wav" file data to the GUI data struct
my_guidata.sampled_data=sampled_data
my_guidata.sample_rate=sample_rate
% Store the GUI data with the ".wav" data
guidata(gcf,my_guidata)
```

Hope this helps,

Qapla'

Comment: I tried the above code, code runs fine and I can process data ..but it don't appear in work space .. Anywasys Thanks for your suggestion.. il_raffa

Comment: If you use the above code inside a function you have to define it so that it returns the values you want in the workspace (something like `[f_name,f_path,sts,sampled_data,sample_rate]=my_function(input_1, input_2)`. with this you define a function which requires 2 input, and returns in the workspace the of the file, its path and the ".wav" data. If you are working with a GUI (created with GUIDE) you can use the OutputFcn.